# Android - Supporting Different Screens

Tags: android, canvas, screen, resolution

I'm programming for a little game in android, but i'm stuck at understanding how the scaling of drawables work or should be done.

I'm drawing a Tilemap in a View on a Canvas with Canvas.drawBitmap()

Main problem is that i don't know how i should manage bitmaps to occupy the same space independent of screen resolution.

My Tile is 64x64 png file and it's placed in drawables folder. Then if i want it to occupy the same space in a xxhdpi screen what should i do?

Should i place in drawables-xxhdpi folder the same tile but as a 192x192 file? Or should i convert px to dps for the drawBitmap() method? Or is there something else?

I'm getting really confused trying out things, and i see myself not getting anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You should keep a bitmap file with different resolutions in different drawables folder. That allows the application to fetch the required files automatically on the basis of the size of device the user uses.

Comment: There is something i'm not doing right, i have placed in drawable-mdpi a 64x64 png file and in drawable-xxhdpi a 192x192 png file. I still can't get to view the same quantity of tiles in both screens... Why?

Comment: quantity or quality?    36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density. You also need to set the size of your bit map as you require.  See this    http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Quantity, if my tilemap in mdpi screen shows perfectly the 8x8 tiles. I want to achieve the same in the xxhdpi screen. Same screen space occupied. I'm already adapting size of the drawBitmap() depending on the density of the screen. So if the virtual device has xxhdpi i use drawBitmap(tile, x*192, y*192, paint); and if is mdpi drawBitmap(tile, x*64, y*64, paint); Is this wrong?

Comment: Did you divide the canvans(where the tiles are to be drawn) height and width by 8 and given the same size to the bitmaps?